# Pandas DataFrame: Concat and to_excel output

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to write a xls file after concatenating three DataFrames with pandas

```
qq=rand(3,3)
qqq=pd.DataFrame(qq)
q=pd.concat([qqq,qqq,qqq],axis=1)
q.to_excel('foo.xlsx')#it's the same with xls
```

The output that I obtain is:
(in the first row there are column names and in the first column the row names)

```
    0   1   2   0   1   2   0   1   2
0   0   1   2   0   1   2   0   1   2
1   0   1   2   0   1   2   0   1   2
2   0   1   2   0   1   2   0   1   2
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That looks like a bug to me in the treatment of repeated columns.  I can reproduce in 0.12.0-559-ga11e143, and the problem goes away if I renumber the columns with `q.columns = range(len(q.columns))`.  If I make the columns `[0, 0, 2, .., 8]`, then you see a partial problem.

Comment: this is fixed when using the ``xlswriter`` engine...., see here: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/5235

Comment: update: this is fixed in current master..

Comment: @Jeff: you should make that an answer so we can close this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is fixed in current master via https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/5235